# Connect application with database on host system and expose the application on a port

Tags: docker

I have installed MariaDB on Ubuntu (not as a Docker image). Then I have an image with a Spring Boot Application. This Spring Boot application should be reachable on port 8002 and be able to connect to MariaDB on the host system.

If I start `docker run` without `--network=host`, the Spring Boot application in the docker image cannot connect to the database.

If I use the `--network=host` parameter, the Spring Boot application can connect to the database, but the application is not reachable on port 8002.

```bash
docker run \
   -e "DB_URL=jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/app" \
   -e "DB_USERNAME=***" \
   -e "DB_PASSWORD=***" \
   -it \
   -p 8002:8080 \
   --network=host \
   repository/app:0.0.3
```

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND            CREATED         STATUS          PORTS       NAMES
2fe96a608298   repository/app:0.0.3    "java -jar app…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes                hardcore_hopper
```

I have tried many. But I can't get the application to be reachable on a port.

Comment: You do not need host networking for most typical applications.  Among other problems with it, it outright just doesn't work if you're using Docker Desktop or a similar VM-based system.  Do the other solutions to [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) help you establish a database connection (it will _not_ be on 127.0.0.1), in a way where normal Docker networking still works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/) you are telling docker that you use the host's networking stack therefore you cannot expose ports on your container. Your application should be running as if it was directly running on your host, meaning you should be able to reach it at port `8080`.

To quote the [documentation on the host network driver](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/):

> If you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not get its own IP-address allocated. For instance, if you run a container which binds to port 80 and you use host networking, the container’s application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.

I am assuming you are on a Linux operating system, since host networking does not work on Windows machines.

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.